# Connect Four Vertical Winner

Tags: java

For some reason this method does not add 1 to col in the outer for loop when the inner four loops are done running. I can only get vertical connect fours in the column that col is set to. For example if col was equal to 2 the computer would only recognize a vertical connect four in column 2. What is wrong?

```
public Player colWinner(){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++){
            for(int row = 0; row < grid.length/2; row++){
                Player currP = getCell(row,col);
                if((currP == getCell(row + 1, col)) && (currP == getCell(row + 2, col)) && (currP == getCell(row + 3, col))){ 
                    return currP;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            for(int row = grid.length/2; row < grid.length; row++){
                Player currP = getCell(row,col);
                if((currP == getCell(row - 1, col)) && (currP == getCell(row - 2, col)) && (currP == getCell(row - 3, col))){ 
                    return currP;
                }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What are the rules of the game that this is meant to manage? In particular, what is `colWinner` meant to do?

Comment: This is a method for the game Connect Four. colWinner is a method that tries to find four pieces in a row in a column.

Comment: OK, I found the game in Wikipedia, but a link would have been nice. I take it ‘four loops’ should be ‘for loops’! You are saying that `col++` does not execute correctly, are you? Have you stepped through this in a debugger, and checked what value `col` has before and after the loop-control is executed, and where control goes? What do you expect `else continue` to do?

Comment: I have not yet looked at this method in a debugger but I will now. Else continue, according to my tutor, will keep the loop going and move onto the next row and continue to check each piece in that column to see if there is a connect four.

Comment: But what do you expect to happen if you leave out `else continue`?

Comment: If I left out else continue I think the method would stop running? Never mind I just commented out else continue and it still ran but it still only allowed  a connect four in col 0.

Comment: Still no joy? I suggest you use the debugger to see where it goes wrong in the simplest case you can. That seems to be to be when when the first column is empty and the second column has the first four rows the same colour. Then step carefully through your logic. Do two things: before you step over a statement, decide what variables it ought to change or where it ought to branch to, and check that it does; when you notice an error (such as a wrong value in a variable) that must have been there for a while, start again and try to find out when it happens.

Comment: P.S. I have been wondering what difference the second nested for-loop is meant to make – I don’t see the point of it.

Comment: The second for loop is suppose to check the second half or the top of the board because if I check for a vertical win from the bottom of the board to the top I get an index out of bound error when it tries to check for four in a row with a piece that starts in slot 5 and up.

Comment: Surely that makes sense: what does a win starting in slot 5 look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code permits the 4 vertical null sequences.
It is required to add `currP != null` for each if statements.

```
public Player colWinner(){
    for(int col = 0; col < grid[0].length; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length/2; row++){
            Player currP = getCell(row,col);
            if(currP != null && currP == getCell(row + 1, col) && currP == getCell(row + 2, col) && currP == getCell(row + 3, col)){ 
                return currP;
            }
        }
        for(int row = grid.length/2; row < grid.length; row++){
            Player currP = getCell(row,col);
            if(currP != null && currP == getCell(row - 1, col) && currP == getCell(row - 2, col) && currP == getCell(row - 3, col)){ 
                return currP;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Monserrat: I suggest that now a solution has been suggested you debug your original code again, looking out for what saka says will happen: this will help you to find such mistakes on your own in future.

Comment: OMG thank you!!! Once I added the currP !=null into both for loops I was able to get vertical winners in other columns. Thanks you so much!

Comment: @MonserratPalabrica: Glad to have helped. As far as the top half goes, you still need to think about your limit `grid.length/2` – ask yourself how high up a winning four can start, and what would make sense on a board of a different height. `grid.length/2` would not always be right!

Comment: Seeing this answer made me think the question more interesting, as I think it illustrates a particular sort of mistake that is relatively unusual, a sort of blindness for the unfilled entries – so I voted the question up.